# Yii2 advanced, Unable to verify your data submission error

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using yii2 advanced template to build a website.
when I want to use a form to create a new row it works, but in the second submission or update after a couple of seconds I am getting this error.
I read many of answers here but I dont want to disable crf token and aleardy I have

```
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
```

on my layout `<head/>`

any suggestions!?.

config file:

```
use \yii\web\Request;

$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

// Replace url
$request = new Request();

$baseUrlFront    = str_replace('/backend/web', '/frontend/web', $request->getBaseUrl());
$scriptUrlFront  = str_replace('/backend/web', '/frontend/web', $request->getScriptUrl());

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [

        'user' => [

            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_backendUser', // unique for backend
                'path'=>'/backend/web' , // correct path for the backend app.

            ]
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'regergwer2343423f238h923f9h9234', // unique for backend
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime', // a temporary folder on backend

        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'i18n'            => [
            'translations' => [
                'writesdown' => [
                    'class'          => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath'       => '@app/messages', // if advanced application, set @frontend/messages
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
                    'fileMap'        => [
                        //'main' => 'main.php',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManagerFront' => [
            'class'     => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'scriptUrl' => $scriptUrlFront,
            'baseUrl'   => $baseUrlFront,
        ],
        'urlManagerBack'  => [
            'class'           => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        ],
        'authManager'     => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

layout:

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>

        <title>WritesDown &raquo; <?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
        <?php $this->head() ?>
    </head>
    <body
        class="<?= isset(Yii::$app->params['bodyClass']) ? Yii::$app->params['bodyClass'] : "skin-blue sidebar-mini"; ?>">
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
    <?= $content; ?>
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Comment: add this line in your form :     <input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />

Comment: As i am understanding your two form submit one by one, In this case your csrf token will change because when your form1 submit then csrf token will change. can you please let us know more detail so we can provide what you looking for.

Comment: @Peerbits-BackendTeam I am using activeform this field automatically added

Comment: @nageennayak no not twice after each other assume that you added a row using the form and you keep the page on this form after couple seconds update or resubmit this error appears. also some times appears when I want to login to my backend.

Comment: are you using normal form submission with submit button, or ajax call.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam
with the two cases this error appears ajax and normal submission

Comment: when using normal submission of the form are you using `ActiveForm`? can you add one of the forms that has this problem

Comment: yes active form and all forms are doing this realy i am confused

Comment: you might have to add the config and the layout file too in your Question, as this is not normal that using normal form submission with `ActiveForm` gives `400 bad request` try adding a `beforeAction()` and add `print_r($_POST)` top check the csrf token field is being submitted.

Comment: also try adding a js statement in your view with form and add `console.log(yii.getCsrfToken())` and compare the value with the value submitted by the form, do they match ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I added the config file and layout

Comment: cant find anything to point out here. did you verified the `csrf`  value ?

Comment: In form crf token exists but when submit i got this error and console show nothing

Answer (score -1):

1. One solution could be this but **recommended only in special case!!!**

Disable csrf check on one Controller's all Actions

```
Add the follow code to controller part:
   public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

2. Use this :

   public function beforeAction($action)
   {
      $this->enableCsrfValidation = false; 
      return parent::beforeAction($action); 
   }